# How to use Kafka+log4cxx for log aggregation

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, log4j, log4cxx

I used log4cxx as the log module in my C++ project. Now I want to manage my debug logs more properly. A possible approach is to use Apache Kafka. I know it is ok to use Kafka in a Java project where log4j is adopted. But when it comes to log4cxx, what is the solution, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps will help you:
[Integrating log4cxx and kafka](https://serverfault.com/questions/631006/integrating-log4cxx-and-kafka) and
see the code of the [klogd](https://github.com/leandrosilva/klogd).

Unfortunately log4cxx has no Kafka appender like it is already done for Log4j2.

Maybe you may write you own dedicated appender for log4cxx based on what is made in Kafka appender for Log4j2 [KafkaAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#KafkaAppender).

Comment: Thanks! By the way, do you know any other viable approaches for centralized log management in a C++ project which uses log4cxx, please?

Comment: Depending on requirements. I had examinned two solutions: 1. For small setups, we had been using dedicated solution based on YAMI4 library. 2. For servers I can recommend: log4cxx to file and there you install Filebeat and/or Logstash depending on system size and then either logstash sends data directly to Elasticsearch or to Kafka.